# How to save and load state in each scene in flash

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, adobe

I am beginner in AS3.

I am currently working on Adobe AIR android app where a user can select and read visual stories.

My Scene 1 is the library of stories. When I click on a certain book of a story on scene 1,  it will go to another scene where that story's pages will play.

I would like to do the function where each story the user had start reading can save the state or part of the story where they stop once they go back to main or exit the app, and load or go to the part where I stop reading once I go back to continue reading the story.

Is there a way to do it in AS3? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Store progress in [Shared Objects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) every time user starts reading or progress. Now every time user is back (after going back to main or exiting the app) and wants to keep reading you check Shared Objects for stored data and if there is just navigate there.

Comment: First of all, stop thinking in terms of scenes. Mixing programming and timelines will not end good. You need to use some kind of architecture and build your application according to this architecture. I advise to start with MVC pattern, it goes pretty good with Flash: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Knowing what you've tried helps people give you a better answer.